# How can I make this query

Tags: sql

I've a in my database file the following:

1- Customer name

2- Customer location

3- Deliveries over last 60 months, so `n` in the table below is `60` sometimes more

```sh
locations × n
│ Row │ Customer │ location │ M0      │ M1       │ M2    │ ...   │ Mn
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼───────┼───────┼──────
│ 1   │ x        │ X1       │ 5       │ 4        │ 5     │ ...   │ 3    
│ 2   │ x        │ X2       │ 3       │ 3        │ 4     │ ...   │ 5     
│ 3   │ y        │ X3       │ 6       │ 3        │ 4     │ ...   │ 5
```

How can I write an SQL statememnt that do the following:

1- Exclude location

2- Group by customer, so that ineach month, the number became the sum of deliveries for all locations with this customer under the given month, something as below:

```sh
customers × n
│ Row │ Customer │ M0      │ M1       │ M2    │ ...   │ Mn  
├─────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼───────┼───────┼───
│ 1   │ x        │ 8       │ 7        │ 9     │ ...   │ 8     
│ 2   │ y        │ 6       │ 3        │ 4     │ ...   │ 5
```

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. (Horrible table design, it should be one M per row.)

Comment: @jarlh I throught to do `Groupby` for the 60 Ms, but hope there is a better way?

Comment: Better design is the solution.

Comment: @jarlh any idea about better design?

Comment: As I said, it should be one M-value per row. Perhaps in a separate table.

Comment: Before attempting to write a query, learn some database design, and fix your tables.  Then we'll talk about querying.

Comment: @Eric any proposal how to fix this model?

Comment: @HasanAYousef Not here.  You need to review your whole system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `SUM` and `Group By`. Try Like:

```
Select Customer,SUM(M0),SUM(M1),SUM(M2),...,SUM(MN) From Customers GROUP BY Customer
```

Comment: Do I need to do all these sum `SUM(M0),SUM(M1),SUM(M2),...,SUM(MN)`

Comment: @HasanAYousef: not if you fix your data model and normalize it. But with the current model: yes, there is no way around it

Comment: Any proposal about fixing the model I've.